# Why is this parallelized script not returning the correct result?

Tags: python, asynchronous, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I'm trying to learn how to use Python's `multiprocessing` module. Playing around with it, I've tried to write the same code both in a non-parallelized and a parallelized manner. The problem is that they are returning different results.

Here is the non-parallelized version:

```
import numpy as np

m = 3
num_points = 200
iterMax = 20
NMax = 3
np.random.seed(0)
y = np.random.rand(num_points,m)
w = list(range(NMax - 1))

for N in range(NMax-1):
    w[N] = np.random.uniform(0,1,(N+2,np.size(y,axis=1))) - 0.5
    iterCount = 1
    while iterCount < iterMax:
        for selectedInput in y:
            w[N] = w[N] + (np.random.rand() - 0.5) * selectedInput
        iterCount += 1    

for i in w:
    print(i)
```

Here's the parallelized version:

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp

m = 3
num_points = 200
iterMax = 20
NMax = 3
np.random.seed(0)
y = np.random.rand(num_points,m)

def neuron_run(N):
    w = np.random.uniform(0,1,(N+2,np.size(y,axis=1))) - 0.5 # Initialize weights
    iterCount = 1
    while iterCount < iterMax:
        for selectedInput in y: 
            w = w + (np.random.rand() - 0.5) * selectedInput
        iterCount += 1    
    return w

if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = []
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=NMax)
    for N in range(NMax-1):
        pool_result = pool.apply_async(neuron_run, args = (N,))
        w.append(pool_result.get())
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    for i in w:
        print(i)
```

Both should return the same `w` because of this line: `np.random.seed(0)`. But they are not.

Where is the mistake? I'm not being able to spot it.

Comment: You know have several processes that manipulate your data in parallel chuncks starting with the same random seed, which isn't the same as a single process manipulating your data serially using the same random seed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `seed` forces repeatability of "random" results, yes.

But if you run several processes in parallel, then each of them has its own seed and random values.

For example, if a single-process code with `seed` produces these six "random" values: 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, then executing one `random` in six processes in parallel will produce just the first value (5) in each of them. Likewise, executing two `random` calls in three processes will generate "random" values 5 and 6 in each of them.

In other words, don't expect `random.seed` to do what you want in multiple processes. That will never work.